# How can i Extract Dimention - Fact connection Data from cube?

Tags: ssas, cube

is there away to extract cube connections between fact and Dimensions as they are defined in the dimension usage ?

in connection i mean the  Dimension Table and  key columns as well as  Measure group name, Columns  as they are defined in the dimention usage

i am aware of  ssas DMV  as well as analysis server Stored procedure project (codeplex) but couldn't find my answer there .

thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the BIDS Helper [Printer Friendly Dimension Usage](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/PrinterFriendlyDimensionUsage/) feature or [Column Usage Reports](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/ColumnUsageReports/) feature accomplish what you want?

Were you just wanting a PDF for documentation? If you need the C# code so you can embed it in your own program let me know.

Comment: thanks !  @GregGalloway i wasent aware of that feature , it is just what i needed.

Comment: by the way is there a similar option or an elegant way in  BIDS to  recieve Data about  Dimention attributes and Measures   Source Tables_Columns without using DMV or analysis server Stored procedure project (codeplex) wich i find somewhat not stright forward

Comment: The closest I can think of is Column Usage Reports https://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Column%20Usage%20Reports&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Or you might look at DOC xPress which is a paid product. http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Doc-xPress